# Submit form with jquery, validate before submit

Tags: jquery, validation

what im trying to do is submit a form with jquery, example submit form to www.mywebsite.com/submit/ and to get the data from there and put on div, but before to submit i need to validate if the input values is correct or not ...

This is my html form:

```
     <form id="Submit_Video" method="get" action="submit/">
      <input id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="Title?"  onfocus="if(value=='Title?')value='';" onblur="if(value=='')value='Title?';" /><br />
      <input id="Weburl" name="Weburl" type="text" value="http://" /><br />

      <select id="Category" name="Category">
       <option value='1'>Value 1</option>
       <option value='2'>Value 2</option>
       <option value='3'>Value 3</option>
       <option value='4'>Value 4</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" id="vsubmit" class="input2" value="Submit" />
     </form>


 <div id="video_submit_response"></div>
```

I put my code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/BxZCt/

The code what i have right now the problem is when you press submit he don't check if its correct the input values or not ... hope someone can help me to show me how i can make the output of www.mywebsite.com/submit/ to be on ID video_submit_response

Comment: In addition to any external links or jsFiddle demos, also show the code in your OP to make the question fully "self-contained".

Answer (score 0):

You had to bind onsumbit function, that will check the inputs for right value. Also you can validate url with HTML5 setting type to this input as `type="url"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 validators with a required attribute, a pattern attribute (that take a regex) and set the type of your input to url..

The HTML5 validators are not compatible FOR IE6 to IE9 (include).

Another solution is to implement the onsubmit listener on your form to do the validation manually ...

If you need examples ask it.

Hope it helps.